# Looping through an object with a suffix in the property name

Tags: php, foreach

The object I that gets returned when I jsonDecode comes out as below with post having a suffix of _0, _1, etc.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
  ["post_0"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
    ["title"]=> ... }
  ["post_1"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
    ["title"]=> ... }
```

How can I loop through all of the `post_` property names to get title, description, etc using:

```
$data=$file_contents->***property_name***;
foreach($data as $info){...
```

Comment: You can foreach over an object (especially stdClass) just like you can over an array.

Comment: stdClass implements `Iterator`, so you can simply `foreach()` it like any other "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do foreach an object just like you are doing on the array.Like

```
foreach($array as $arrays) {
// ur condition
}
```